# Алгоритм разбора входных данных в дерево

Tags: дерево, javascript, алгоритм, php

Дан входной массив значений в виде строки:

```
(p (b "sometext")(p (table (columns (column "One") (column "Two") (column "Three"))  
(body (row (cell "111.1") (cell "111.2") (cell "111.3") nil nil)  
(row (cell "222.1") (cell "222.2") (cell "222.3") nil nil)  
(row (cell "333.1") (cell "333.2") (cell "333.3") nil nil)))))
```

Это все. Необходимо разобрать в XML или HTML средствами javascript или php. Не могу найти алгоритм, который поможет мне из списка построить дерево и это дерево в дальнейшем отработать. Приведенная строка для разбора - это фрагмент, данных на самом деле больше, но структура их в общем такова.
Подскажите с алгоритмом или дайте ссылку на реализацию, то что нашел я - не могу прилепить к своей задаче. Желательно не использовать сложных компонентов типа treeview, а обойтись массивами или списками.

Comment: все в принципе реально, но вот непонятно, что делать с nil

Comment: покажите реальный пример!!!
три дня гуглю, на всех ресурсах пишут "та это все просто" но кода никто не показывает

Comment: это просто записано в lisp стиле. Парсер то я могу написать, поэтому и спрашиваю, как парсер должен трактовать nil.

Comment: допустим, как пробел (_&nbsp;_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буквально пара секунд гугления и находится [сайт](http://taliesin.nvg.org/language/). Там есть конвертор list2xml, правда он на питоне.
Дорабатывается немножко напильником и готово!

**upd:**
А вот и код на php. PHP я знаю очень плохо, поэтому, код нужно будет допиливать до нужного состояния. По предоставленному кусочку лисп-кода он генерит валидный xml.

```
<?php

class Lisp2XML_FST {
    public $_prev;
    public $_tags;
    public function __construct($root="root", $empty="empty", $readfrom='') {
        $this->emptytag = $empty;
        $this->roottag = $root;
        $this->readfrom = $readfrom;
        $this->_tags = array();
        $this->_prev = '';
    }

    public function is_startparens() {
        $this->is_tag();
        array_push($this->_tags, "");
    }

    public function is_tag() {
        $l = count($this->_tags);
        if ($this->_tags[$l -1] != "") {
            $prevtag = $this->_tags[$l -1];
        } else {
            $prevtag = $this->emptytag;
        }
        $this->_tags[$l - 1] = $prevtag;
        $this->write("<".$prevtag.">");
    }

    public function is_endparens() {
        $tag = array_pop($this->_tags);
        $this->write("</".$tag.">\n");
    }

    public function write($something) {
        echo($something); #весь вывод - только через эту функцию
    }

    public function comment($char) {
        if (char == "\n") {
            return $this->_prev;
        } else {
            return "comment";
        }
    }

    public function starttag($char) {
        $this->_prev = "starttag";
        if (($char == " ") or ($char == "\n") or ($char == "\t")) {
            return "starttag";
        } else if ($char == "(") {
            array_push($this->_tags, "");
            return "intag";
        } else if ($char == "%") {
            return "comment";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public function intag($char) {
        $this->_prev = "intag";
        if ($char == "(") {
            $this->is_startparens();
            return "intag";
        } elseif (($char == " ") or ($char == "\n") or ($char == "\t")) {
            $l = count($this->_tags);
            if ($this->_tags[$l-1] == "") {
                echo("tag\n");
                return "intag";
            } else {
                $this->is_tag();
                return "indata";
            }
        } else if ($char == "%") {
            return "comment";
        } else if ($char == ")") {
            $this->is_endparens();
            return "indata";
        } else {
            $l = count($this->_tags);
            $this->_tags[$l-1] .= $char;
            return "intag";
        }
    }

    public function indata($char) {
        $this->_prev = "indata";
        $default = "indata";
        if ($char == "(") {
            array_push($this->_tags, "");
            return "intag";
        } else if ($char == ")") {
            $this->is_endparens();
            return $default;
        } else if (($char == " ") or ($char == "\n") or ($char == "\t")) {
            $this->write($char);
            return $default;
        } else if ($char == "%") {
            return "comment";
        } else {
            $this->write($char);
            return $default;
        }
    }

    public function error($char) {
        return "";
    }
};

function convert($root="root", $empty="empty", $readfrom="") {
    $fst = new Lisp2XML_FST($root, $empty, $readfrom);
    $fst->write("<".$fst->roottag.">");
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($readfrom); $i++) {
        $char = $readfrom[$i];
        if (count($fst->_tags) == 0) {
            $next = "starttag";
            $fst->write("\n");
        }
        $prev = $next;
        $next = $fst->$next($char);
        if ($next == "") {
            if (count($fst->_tags) != 0) {
                $fst->is_endparens();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count($fst->_tags)) {
        $fst->is_endparens();
    }
    $fst->write("</".$fst->roottag.">\n");
}
?>

<?php
#пример использования
$s = '(p (b "sometext")(p (table (columns (column "One") (column "Two") (column "Three"))'.
     '(body (row (cell "111.1") (cell "111.2") (cell "111.3") nil nil)'.
     '(row (cell "222.1") (cell "222.2") (cell "222.3") nil nil)'.
     '(row (cell "333.1") (cell "333.2") (cell "333.3") nil nil)))))';
convert('root', 'empty', $s);
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю, но мой напильник не понимает питон...

Comment: Питон не сложен. Если я и смогу переписать на пхп, то это только вечером.

Comment: Буду крайне признателен!!!

Comment: Отличненько! Огромная благодарность!!! Пошел пилить..